# How do I include zip file in NSBundle?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcodebuild

I'd like to include a zip file as an attachment to in app email (OS 3.0).  I've added the file to my Xcode project and get this message during building:

Checking Dependencies
warning: skipping file '/Users/account1/Developer/Doc4_5.zip' (unexpected file type 'archive.zip' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)

Is there something else I need to do or another technique to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move your ZIP archive from the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase to the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase. Open up your target with the disclosure triangle, and drag it from one to the other.

I'd guess that it ends up in the Libraries phase as an unexpected side-effect of the Java support built into Xcode.